# Set Multiple markers with Angular 4 and google maps

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Hello Everyone need Help setting Multiple markers to google map component in Angular 4. I can get a single Marker to show up with this code.

```
 ngOnInit() {
    const myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.748817, -73.985428);
    const mapOptions = {
        zoom: 13,
        center: myLatlng,
        scrollwheel: false

    };
    const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
    const Marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        title: 'Hello World!'
    });
    // To add the marker to the map, call setMap();
    Marker.setMap(map);


}
```

How can I modify this to show multiple locations. I have locations in from JSON like below.

```
    {
        "locations": [
            {
                "_id": "59eb784fa8e0be0004fb466e",
                "updatedAt": "2017-10-21T16:39:43.338Z",
                "createdAt": "2017-10-21T16:39:43.338Z",
                "latitude": "0.2346285",
                "longitude": "32.4352628",
                "locationName": "Prime warehouse A",
                "locationInfo": "Kampala Warehouse #001",
                "__v": 0
            },
            {
                "_id": "1568eb54560be000456466e",
                "updatedAt": "2018-10-21T16:39:43.448Z",
                "createdAt": "2016-09-11T16:39:43.338Z",
                "latitude": "4.3346285",
                "longitude": "32.4352628",
                "locationName": "Prime warehouse A",
                "locationInfo": "Kampala Warehouse #001",
                "__v": 0
            }
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as you can access your `locations` array, then you can loop through it and from there create a marker each.

Here's a sample if you put everything in your `ngOnInit` function:

```
ngOnInit() {
  let map;
  const locations; // if you have your locations hard-coded, else just make sure it's accessible

  const myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.748817, -73.985428);
  const mapOptions = {
    zoom: 13,
    center: myLatlng,
    scrollwheel: false

};

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);


  // loop through each object of your locations array
  for (let location in locations) {

    // The marker's position property needs an object like { lat: 0, lng: 0 };
    // Number(location.latitude) is there to convert the string to a number, but if it's a number already, there's no need to cast it further.
    let latLng = {lat: Number(location.latitude), lng: Number(location.longitude)};

    // Set the position and title
    let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: latLng,
      title: location.locationName
  })

    // place marker in map
    marker.setMap(map)
  }
}
```

You can learn more about importing data into a Map with [Google's official documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/importing_data)

Hope that helps!

Comment: I seem to be getting an `ERROR ReferenceError: google is not defined` on ngOnit and the map is not loaded

Comment: Okay managed to fix that error by simply adding time delay of 15 seconds using setTimeOut function. `ngOnInit() {

        setTimeout(() => {
            this.loadMap();
        }, 1500);

    }`   Then moved the rest of the code into a loadMap function. It now works flawlessly. Thanks for the help @henrisycip

Comment: Glad you got it to work. If my answer has helped you, please consider accepting it so that others can learn from it as well. Thanks!

Comment: It appears its hard to auto update the markers without reloading the whole canvas - @henrisycip do you have any ideas on this. Right now my solution involves using the setInterval function to reload the whole map

Comment: It would be best to post another question about this to get more people on it. One strategy would be to not reload the canvas, just clear markers and set them again on the map.

Comment: `for (let location in locations) {` is wrong as it should be: `for (let location of locations) {`